# React Material-UI styling active menu items

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to apply css styles to `:active` and `:hover` states of a Material-UI Menu.

The docs say,

> selectedMenuItemStyle | object | | Override the inline-styles of selected menu items.

But applying,

```
<Menu selectedMenuItemStyle={{ color: 'red'}}>
 <MenuItem
   style={ menuItemStyles }
   primaryText={ pages.dashboard.title.toUpperCase() }
   containerElement={<NavLink to={ `${pages.dashboard.slug}` } />} />
</Menu>
```

has no effect when I click on `<MenuItem>`

I've also tried React-Router's `activeStyle` and `activeClassName` which have no effect because Material-UI overrides them.

Anyone know how to apply `:active` and `:hover` correctly?

Comment: May be here is your answere https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623914/how-to-set-focus-on-a-menuitem-in-material-ui?answertab=active#tab-top --by Cesar Ho

Answer (score 0):

Have a look there  : [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/styles)

> Every component provides a className property. Those properties are always applied to the root element.
>   Note that CSS properties defined inline are given priority over those defined in a CSS class. You need to use !important to take precedence over the inline style.

try to add `!important` on your custom style to override material-ui like

```
.test-class:hover {
  color: red !important
}
```