# How to set focus on a MenuItem in material-ui

Tags: menu, focus, menuitem, material-ui

I am trying to programmatically set focus on (activate) one of the MenuItem(s) inside the Menu component in material-ui. I can manually do it by tabbing to it but I need to do it programmatically in response to a key down event.

```
<Menu disableAutoFocus={true}>
   <MenuItem .../>
   <MenuItem .../>
   ...
</Menu>
```

Comment: this may be of use http://stackoverflow.com/a/37964596/1908184

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by select the menuItem programmatically? If so, you can use the concept of 'controlled component'.

Here is the example, 
If this.state.selectedItem = 1, the item 'Maps' will be selected.
If this.state.selectedItem = 2, the item 'Books' will be selected.

```
  <Menu
    selectedMenuItemStyle={ {backgroundColor: '#c00', color: '#FFFFFF'} }
    value={this.state.selectedItem}
    >
      <MenuItem primaryText="Maps" value='1'/>
      <MenuItem primaryText="Books" value='2' />
  </Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `autoFocus` property like this:

```
<MenuItem autoFocus tabIndex={3}></MenuItem>
```